# Evaluate $ \prod_{n=3}^\infty ( 1 - \binom{n}{2}^{-1} )$

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients, infinite-product

> $$ \prod_{n=3}^\infty \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{\binom{n}{2}} \right)$$

Expanding it out doesn't give any good patterns, I'm totally stuck.

The answer is 1/3 [according to WolframAlpha: 
 https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+from+3+to+infinity+(1+-+1%2F((n)+comb+2)+)

Comment: The index of the product is $i$ or $n$ ?

Comment: it must be $$\prod_{i=3}^{\infty}1-\frac{1}{\binom{i}{2}}$$

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited it.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\prod_{n=3}^N \left(1-\frac{1}{\binom{n}{2}}\right)&=\prod_{n=3}^N \left(1-\frac{2}{n(n-1)}\right)\\\\
&=\prod_{n=3}^N\frac{n^2-n-2}{n(n-1)}\\\\
&=\prod_{n=3}^N \frac{n+1}{n}\frac{n-2}{n-1}\\\\
&=\prod_{n=3}^N \frac{n+1}{n}\prod_{n=3}^N \frac{n-2}{n-1}\\\\
&=\frac{N+1}{3}\frac{1}{N-1}
\end{align}$$

Now let $N\to \infty$.

Comment: Gorgeous, gorgeous, gorgeous telescoping products. Well done! +1

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thank you my friend!

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$1-\dfrac1{\binom n2}=\dfrac{n^2-n-2}{n(n-1)}=\dfrac{(n+1)(n-2)}{n(n-1)}=\dfrac{f(n)}{f(n-2)}$$ where $f(m)=\dfrac{m+1}m$

$$\prod_{n=3}^r\dfrac{f(n)}{f(n-2)}=?$$

Answer (score 2):

**Taking the logarithm:** *(Not necessarily the fastest way here, but in general a good idea for infinite products: you convert these products into series, and we usually know better how to deal with series. Also, logarithms of fractions often lead to telescopic terms.)*

$$\begin{align}
\ln \prod_{n=3}^\infty \left(1-\binom{n}{2}^{-1}\right)
&= \sum_{n=3}^\infty \ln\left(1-\binom{n}{2}^{-1}\right)
= \sum_{n=3}^\infty \ln\left(1-\frac{2}{n(n-1)}\right) \\
&= \sum_{n=3}^\infty \ln\left(\frac{n^2-n-2}{n(n-1)}\right)
= \sum_{n=3}^\infty \ln\left(\frac{(n-2)(n+1)}{n(n-1)}\right)\\
&= \sum_{n=3}^\infty \left( \ln(n+1) - \ln n-\ln(n-1)+\ln(n-2) \right)
\end{align}$$
Now, let us see what telescopes: for $N\geq 3$,
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=3}^N &\left( \ln(n+1) - \ln n-\ln (n-1)+\ln(n-2) \right)
\\&= \sum_{n=3}^N \ln(n+1)-\sum_{n=3}^N \ln n-\sum_{n=3}^N \ln (n-1) +\sum_{n=3}^N \ln(n-2)
\\&= \sum_{n=4}^{N+1} \ln n -\sum_{n=3}^N \ln n -\sum_{n=2}^{N-1} \ln n  +\sum_{n=1}^{N-2} \ln n
\\&= \ln(N+1) - \ln 3 - \ln (N-1) + \ln 1 \\
&= \ln\frac{N+1}{N-1} - \ln 3
\end{align}
The first term converges to $\ln 1=0$, so the limit overall is $-\ln 3$. So your original quantity converges, by continuity of $\exp$, to $\boxed{e^{-\ln 3} = \frac{1}{3}}$.

**Edit:** as mentioned in a comment below: here, clearly one can show the show that the product "telescopes" directly, as Mark Viola does in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2523451/75808). However, the point here is to illustrate the use of logarithms to convert products to sums -- it's more general, and is a very good technique to prove convergence/divergence or even obtain asymptotics (when computing the exact value is not easy, or impossible).

Comment: Hi CC ... This suffices, but why not just show that the product "telescopes" directly.

Comment: @MarkViola Well, you had done it already. I mostly wanted to illustrate the use of logarithms to convert products to sums -- it's more general, and is a very good technique to prove convergence/divergence or even obtain asymptotics (when computing the exact value is not easy, or impossible).

Comment: In that case (+1)

Answer (score 0):

for the definite product we get
$$\prod_{i=1}^m1-\frac{1}{\binom{i}{2}}=1/3\,{\frac {\Gamma  \left( m+2 \right) \Gamma  \left( m-1 \right) }{
\Gamma  \left( m \right) \Gamma  \left( m+1 \right) }}
$$

Comment: Maybe filling in the intermediate steps would help the OP? In that, right now your answer is actually less detailed, and more complicated, than the [partial product formula given by WolframAlpha in the link provided by the OP themselves.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+from+3+to+infinity+(1+-+1%2F((n)+comb+2)+))